# MongoDB 2.4 - Aggreation group by date with 120 days interval

Tags: mongodb, date, intervals, aggregation

i hope someone can help me with my actual problem. I working since 2 month with MongoDB and in past i was only working with SQL databases, this is why thinking in mongoDB is not that easy for me.

I looked already at several examples within the Forum but i am not able to adapt them to my problem.

I have a big collection with gamers and gameresults.

The collection looks like:

```
> db.gameresults.find({"player": 6805}).pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("c5b037807ab6cc37951a0000"),
"player" : 6805,
"birthdate" : ISODate("1999-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
"gender" : "m",
"race" : "ASIAN",
"playedgames" : [
    {
        "vGameName" : "GameA",
        "highscore" : 36.20000076293945,
        "hsDate" : ISODate("2015-07-20T01:01:00Z"),
    },
    {
        "vGameName" : "GameA",
        "highscore" : 13,
        "hsDate" : ISODate("2015-08-03T01:02:00Z"),
    },
    {
        "vGameName" : "GameB",
        "highscore" : 55,
        "hsDate" : ISODate("2015-08-03T01:01:00Z"),
    },
    {
        "vGameName" : "GameC",
        "highscore" : 104,
        "hsDate" : ISODate("2015-11-08T09:30:00Z"),
    },
    {
        "vGameName" : "GameA",
        "highscore" : 81,
        "hsDate" : ISODate("2015-06-03T11:04:00Z"),
    },
    {
        "vGameName" : "GameC",
        "highscore" : 21,
        "hsDate" : ISODate("2016-12-03T11:04:00Z"),
    },
    {
        "vGameName" : "GameB",
        "highscore" : 7.170000076293945,
        "hsDate" : ISODate("2016-09-08T09:30:00Z"),
    }
]
```

}

Now i tried to create a aggregation on my collection to get a result that is showing me the following:

Average highscore within a 120 days time range, starting from smallest date sorted by player.

The result should look like, but within a 120 days intervall:

```
{ "_id" : { "player" : 6805, "hsDate" : ISODate("2015-06-03T00:00:00Z") }, "avgHighscore" : 51 }
{ "_id" : { "player" : 6805, "hsDate" : ISODate("2015-06-07T00:00:00Z") }, "avgHighscore" : 9.520000457763672 }
{ "_id" : { "player" : 6805, "hsDate" : ISODate("2015-06-08T00:00:00Z") }, "avgHighscore" : 60.50477317381989 }
{ "_id" : { "player" : 6805, "hsDate" : ISODate("2015-06-10T00:00:00Z") }, "avgHighscore" : 5.766666730244954 }
{ "_id" : { "player" : 6805, "hsDate" : ISODate("2016-06-14T00:00:00Z") }, "avgHighscore" : 9.5600004196167 }
{ "_id" : { "player" : 6805, "hsDate" : ISODate("2016-06-15T00:00:00Z") }, "avgHighscore" : 57.574060224220155 }
```

Results after the 120 days, should start with a new interval.
I tried now for more than one week to figure out how to resolve this but the only way i found was a daily interval and i was not able to improve it to 120 days.

**Also i was trying to use the suggestions within this forum from similar solutions for minutes, seconds or hours. But i was not able to change them to work with my 120 days interval.**

**Old MySQL Data looks like:**

> ```
> player    highscore   hsDate
> 6805      81          2015-06-03 12:04:00
> 6805      21          2015-06-03 12:04:00
> 6805      9.52        2015-06-07 21:00:00
> 6805      104         2015-06-08 10:30:00
> 6805      7.17        2015-06-08 10:30:00
> 6805      2.54        2015-06-08 10:30:00
> 6805      8.2         2015-06-08 10:30:00
> 6805      25.5        2015-06-08 10:30:00
> ```

**My Code for 1 day interval is looking at the moment like:**

```
db.gameresults.aggregate(
        { $unwind : "$playedgames" },
        { "$project" : { "player" : 1, "playedgames" : 1, "date" : '$playedgames.hsDate', "_id" : 0, "day" : { "$dayOfMonth" : '$playedgames.hsDate' }, "h" : { "$hour" : '$playedgames.hsDate' }, "m" : { "$minute" : '$playedgames.hsDate' }, "s" : { "$second" : '$playedgames.hsDate' }, "ml" : { "$millisecond" : '$playedgames.hsDate' } } },
        { "$project" : { "player" : 1, "playedgames" : 1, "date" : { "$subtract" : [ "$date", { "$add" : [ "$ml", { "$multiply" : [ "$s", 1000 ] }, { "$multiply" : [ "$m", 60, 1000 ] }, { "$multiply" : [ "$h", 60, 60, 1000 ] } ] } ] } } },
        { "$group" : { "_id" : { "player" : "$player", "hsDate" : "$playedgames.hsDate" }, "avg" : { "$avg" : "$playedgames.highscore" } } },
        { $sort: { _id : 1 } }
     )
```

Until now i was not able to get it working with 120 Days interval. The year should also be checked because of year changes.

Please can someone help me to solve this problem.

Greetings,
Eddi

Comment: A time interval is a time interval. All approaches are the same with the only variation being for a month, and that's "almost" the same.

Comment: I have updated the content of my question with more details and with my results according to the suggestions within this forum.

Comment: You know that part where you referrred to ".. or am I wrong". Then look again. Interval means it effectively "rounds down" the amount and you are doing a modulo of "two days". If you expect to go from a "start date" on an odd day then you need to adjust your math. Also this does not make sense to do without an initial query. So if you expect it to begin on a certain day with an "odd number" then add one day to the rounded amount. Principle still remains the same.

Comment: Im so sorry but i can't follow you.

Comment: Hello, i have tried now again for several hours to get to a solution but wihout any success. Maybe i am to stupid but it would be helpfull to have a example for a solution with days or at month.